# How do I change my category? (Windows Phone 7)

Tags: windows-phone-7, categories, marketplace

I am developing a Windows Phone 7 application. I noticed the Genre tag in WMAppManifest.xml, but was unable to do anything useful with it. How can I categorize my application to be a game? And if it's possible add it to a certain category in the games section.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Deployment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsphone/2009/deployment"
            AppPlatformVersion="7.1">
  <App xmlns=""
       ProductID="" 
    Title="" 
    RuntimeType="" 
    Version="" 
    Genre="How can I use this?" 
    Author="" 
    Description="" 
    Publisher="">
```

Comment: Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh221578.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769509(v=vs.92).aspx#BKMK_Application